# How to connect localhost on Mobile over local WIFI?

Tags: android, mobile, dns, iis-7, dhcp

I have a Web API Project hosted on my local system (Windows 7) on IIS7.

I am trying to access that Web API or for that matter another website hosted on the same IIS via my android mobile phone and My Mobile phone is connected to local wifi. But this IIS computer is connected to same network via wired LAN. Though I can access my router that is hosted on "xxx.xxx.1.1" IP Address from that computer as well as mobile phone but i am unable to access the IIS website from my mobile phone.

I tried turning off my windows firewall on the IIS computer where this website is running, but this didn't help as well. Although i can access this IIS website via another computer on the same LAN.

I think the issue is related to LAN or wifi but it should not be as the network and router for LAN and wifi are the same.

Need immediate help and how can i solve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. When it was extremely urgent today, i found the answer myself. It was D link Router problem and here is the solution. Hope this helps others.

Check option Clients isolation in Wireless -> Basic.

If it turned ON - clients from LAN wil not access Wi-Fi clients and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Can you ping your phone from your computer? Or vice-versa?

Access your router configuration and check for any access control setting that might be separating WiFi from LAN.